# Issues with JQuery UI Draggable, stack and zindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been putting together a small personal website that's based on the UI of early Windows. Fully appreciate it's not the most user friendly of designs, but it's mostly for fun.

http://damian.me

Anyway, everything is working broadly as intended (except some IE11 weirdness which I'll fix later).

However...

I am making use of JQuery UI Draggable to allow people to drag windows around. This generally works fine, but I am finding that after a window has been dragged, it no longer obeys its zindex value.

So, for example, if you open a window with a zindex of 1 and then drag it slightly, it will from then on always appear on top of any other element, even if that new element has a higher zindex. Of course, dragging a new element brings it to the front, but then you face the same problem next time.

As an example, if you load the page, click on apps and then click on skifree. The skifree window will load on top. However, if you click on apps, move the window ever so slightly, and then click on skifree, the window will load underneath.

Ideally I'm just looking for a way to ensure that any new window automatically gets pushed right to the front.

I've attached the link to the actual site, but the code I'm using for dragging is:

```js
$(".window").draggable({
  handle: ".window-bar",
  containment: ".desktop",
  scroll: false,
  snap: ".desktop",
  snapMode: "inner",
  stack: ".window"
});
```

And new windows are simply created by showing existing but hidden divs:

```js
 $("a[data-window]").click(function(){
  const windowToOpen = $(this).data("window")
  $("input#start-menu").prop( "checked", false );
  $("#" + windowToOpen).show();
 })
```

I'm not a professional developer so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Also please ignore some of the rough coding - some stuff still needs refining.

Comment: This is cool! ; its not apparent to me how to solve but it looks like the stacking feature might be causing it http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack . The apps window when dragged becomes the topmost and since you are not dragging (the hidden) skifree window ( but just showing) the stack order remains as is. I think you should try triggering drag on skifree's window div.

Comment: I did try and look at triggering draggable programmatically for each new window, but wasn't sure how to accomplish. Couldn't seem to do it. I did experiment with the end option that allows you to set conditions on drag end but it didn't really behave as expected. The documentation for dragging is a little sparse sadly.